# A huge strange problem with an attempt to get the newly created site id

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

So the problem is that I do not know if the id of newly created site will be correct and whether I can use it right after the site will be successfully created. How can I distinguish the correct behavior?

After creating Communication Site using the request to **POST** `/_api/sitepages/communicationsite/create`
with the body:

```
{
    {"request", {
       {"__metadata", {
          {"type", "SP.Publishing.CommunicationSiteCreationRequest"}
        }},
       {"Url", siteInfo.url},
       {"Title", siteInfo.title},
       {"SiteDesignId", siteInfo.designId},
       {"Classification", ""}
     }}
  }
```

the response returns the id of newly created site.

But if I want to get that site id from the request to **GET** `/sites/{hostname}:/{server-relative-path}`
I am facing such a strange behavior (every time id randomly changes!!!):
I`ve executed 11 times the request mentioned above right after the creation of the new site. 
Here is the results

```
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c

---------------

(here, returned right after creation)
site.sharepoint.com,449a607b-0371-434f-98ee-297e33ed913b,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
(/here)
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,69debdca-5186-42c5-82c5-f33a2b6e2a4d,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c

---------------

site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c

---------------

site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,f06c2397-c882-4501-8c99-e2cd6215f085,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c

---------------

site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
(here)
site.sharepoint.com,e5911839-2009-4539-b80c-2d79585b0f49,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
(/here)
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c

---------------

site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
(here)
site.sharepoint.com,27b87d60-2e83-411a-8a00-aec0c9ab8c00,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
(/here)
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
site.sharepoint.com,aece5894-5a84-4d51-ab0c-6ac0488e9a66,651d4c8e-1715-4f77-adbc-66d6bfe60c3c
```

Comment: `GET` API creating a communication site every time you request, is this?

Comment: Yes, 10 times after creation of the site, but without select field